# No class model can be serialized into the ViewModel

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization, xml-serialization, viewmodel

Good afternoon.

I am developing a Silverlight application with WCF Ria Services. I have a set of classes models that need to be serialized for transporting them using WCF, but in my viewmodel, whenever I try to serialize any one of these templates the following error is raised:

***There was an error reflecting type system.Collections tions.Generic.list ' BlocoItem. 1Informa. Model.***

InnerExpection:

System.ServiceModel. DomainServices system.data.Services.client. EntityConflict cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

The classes are fairly simple, most of them contain only primitive types and all have a constructor without parameters. But even so this error happens.

Some have any idea what is happening? I thank you.

Comment: It looks like your class there has a public member which is a Generic List (ie.: `List<MyClass>`) which cannot automatically be serialized.  Is that the case?

Comment: Received the same error when i updated my app from SL4 -> SL5 ... error is due to RIA changes most obviously.

Comment: Naturally all costructors without parameters are public, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that you use ObservableCollections instead of Lists.  These tend to give less trouble serializing.  If for some reason, you have a class from a different library that needs to be serialized, but has not parameter less constructor.  Extend that class by creation a partial one, and define a parameter less constructor.

```
public partial class MyExistingClass
{
     public MyExistingClass():base(){}....
```

More can be found on partial classes here - [MSDN Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)